# SQL Server 2005: Attach database using sp_attach_db with full text catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

Having issues attaching a Database and full text catalog from server A to server B with the "sp_attach_db" command in SQL Server 2005 SP3. All the database files (data, log, full-text catalog) have been copied from server A to server B. I am guessing that this is indeed possible and that my syntax is just incorrect, but I can't seem to find any examples or good documentation anywhere. Here is some pseudo syntax I am using...

```
exec sp_attach_db '<database_name>', '<database data file>', '<database full text catalog folder>', '<database log file>'
```

or somewhat of an example....

```
exec sp_attach_db 'database', 'C:\Database\Data\database_data.mdf', 'C:\Database\Data\FTData', 'C:\Databases\Logs\database_log.ldf'
```

I get an error of "Unable to open the physical file" from this command and the attach command fails. If I remove the full text catalog folder from the sp_attach_db command the database mounts but gives me a warning that it couldn't find the full text catalog. What am I missing!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx). See Example H:

> **Attaching a full-text catalog that has
>   been moved**
>   The following example
>   attaches the full-text catalog
>   AdvWksFtCat along with the
>   AdventureWorks2008R2 data and log
>   files. In this example, the full-text
>   catalog is moved from its default
>   location to a new location
>   c:\myFTCatalogs. The data and log
>   files remain in their default
>   locations.

```
USE master;
GO
--Detach the AdventureWorks2008R2 database
sp_detach_db AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
-- Physically move the full text catalog to the new location.
--Attach the AdventureWorks2008R2 database and specify the new location of the full-text catalog.
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 ON 
    (FILENAME = 'c:\...\Data\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'c:\...\Data\AdventureWorks2008R2_log.ldf'),
    (FILENAME = 'c:\myFTCatalogs\AdvWksFtCat')
FOR ATTACH;
GO
```