# SQL Server 2005: Attach database using sp_attach_db or CREATE DATABASE with multiple filegroups and full text catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

Having issues attaching a Database with multiple filegroups and a full text catalog from server A to server B with either "sp_attach_db" or CREATE DATABASE in SQL Server 2005 SP3. All the database files (primary data, secondary data, log, full-text catalog) have been copied from server A to server B.

I had a similar issue ([SQL Server 2005: Attach database using sp_attach_db with full text catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019060/sql-server-2005-attach-database-using-sp-attach-db-with-full-text-catalog)) but this example only had a primary data file, primary log file and a full text catalog

Now I am faced with adding in more filegroups and when I try to run the example command below it fails

```
CREATE DATABASE DBNAME ON 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\DBNAME_data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\DBNAME_indexes.ndf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\DBNAME1_data.ndf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Logs\DBNAME_log.ldf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\FTData') 
FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

Error Message:

```
Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 1
Unable to open the physical file "C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\FTData". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
```

I have used this Microsoft page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) as my guide but it doesn't have an example like this. I know this has to be possible, what am I missing!?

Answer (score 0):

Try the information in this question/answer: [SQL Server 2005: Attach database using sp_attach_db with full text catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019060/sql-server-2005-attach-database-using-sp-attach-db-with-full-text-catalog)

Comment: I mention that in my post above. That is actually a post from myself before. This example has now changed since there are filegroups

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I needed to do. Whether this is the right way or a work-around way I am not sure. This is what I did....first I removed the fulltext catalog from the create database list since it was having issues with it (no matter how I had it) and was able to create/attach the database (though I did get a warning)

```
CREATE DATABASE DBNAME ON 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\DBNAME_data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\DBNAME_indexes.ndf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\DBNAME1_data.ndf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Logs\DBNAME_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

Then I got the logical name and path to the fulltext catalog from this...

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASE_FILES  WHERE TYPE_DESC = 'FULLTEXT'
```

Then brought the database offline, repathed the fulltext catalog and then brought the database back online with this...

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET OFFLINE
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME MODIFY FILE ( NAME = sysft_cat_full_text , FILENAME = 'C:\Databases\DBNAME\Data\FTData\cat_full_text')
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET ONLINE
```

So far I have not had to rebuild the catalogs yet